# How to fix columns of org-agenda clock report

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock-table

My problem was that the `%` values in org-agenda clock report are in different columns like the image below.

[image]

I wanted the `%` values of my clock report to be in a single column which looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if this has something to do with `org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist` but here is my settings for this variable

```
(setq org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist
  (quote (:link t :maxlevel 7 :fileskip0 t :compact t :narrow 80 :formula %)))
```

I think I messed up my org-mode settings here.

Could you please help me how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you make the level indicators in the form ^-->?

Comment: @user16349
`(defun my-org-clocktable-indent-string (level)
  (if (= level 1)
      ""
    (let ((str "^"))
      (while (> level 2)
        (setq level (1- level)
              str (concat str "--")))
      (concat str "-> "))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after updating org-mode

```
 Status: Installed in ‘org-20170904/’,
         shadowing a built-in package (unsigned). Delete
Version: 20170904
Summary: Outline-based notes management and organizer
```

To update org-mode, evaluate this code:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

Then do the following:

```
M-x list-packages

Select org-mode

Select install
```